# how to show all tabs programatically in macOS SwiftUI App

Tags: macos, swiftui

I want to add an action to **Show All Tabs** programmatically

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Untested: Try calling [toggleTabOverview](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/2870175-toggletaboverview) on NSApp.keyWindow.